# CSV to JSON with Specific format

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, api-design

I Have csv file with  this data and using python i would like to convert in json Format.

I would like to convert in this format Json Format.Can you tell me the which library i should use or any suggestion for sudo code.
I am able to convert in standard json which has key value pair but i don't know how to convert below Json Format.

```
"T-shirt","Long-tshirt",18
"T-shirt","short-tshirt"19
"T-shirt","half-tshirt",20
"top","very-nice",45
"top","not-nice",56
```

```html
{
"T-shirts":[
  {
  "name":"Long-tshirt",
  "size":"18"
  },
  {
  "name":"short-tshirt",
  "size":"19"
  },
  {
  "name":"half-tshirt",
  "size":"20"
  },
  ],
"top":[
  {
  "name":"very-nice"
  "size":45
  },
  {
  "name":"not-nice"
  "size":45
  },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, I put your CSV into `test.csv` file: (as a heads up, the provided code was missing a comma before the `19`).

```
"T-shirt","Long-tshirt",18
"T-shirt","short-tshirt",19
"T-shirt","half-tshirt",20
"top","very-nice",45
"top","not-nice",56
```

Then, using the built-in `csv` and `json` modules you can iterate over each row and add them to a dictionary. I used a `defaultdict` to save time, and write out that data to a `json` file.

```
import csv, json
from collections import defaultdict

my_data = defaultdict(list)

with open("test.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row: # To ignore blank lines
            my_data[row[0]].append({"name": row[1], "size": row[2]})


with open("out.json", "w") as out_file:
    json.dump(my_data, out_file, indent=2)
```

Generated out file:

```
{
  "T-shirt": [
    {
      "name": "Long-tshirt",
      "size": "18"
    },
    {
      "name": "short-tshirt",
      "size": "19"
    },
    {
      "name": "half-tshirt",
      "size": "20"
    }
  ],
  "top": [
    {
      "name": "very-nice",
      "size": "45"
    },
    {
      "name": "not-nice",
      "size": "56"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How can i add the key on the top of the dict so it's look like Type and it value has this output.Do you have any idea about that.

Comment: Hi @Nishit sorry for late reply, I think you are saying you just want another higher level key pair to the dictionary, so last line: `json.dump({"Type": my_data}, out_file, indent=2)`. Basically just wrapping what we transformed into another dictionary to give that layer. `{"Type": my_data}`

Answer (score -3):

```
import json

json_string = json.dumps(your_dict)
```

You now have a string containing json formatted date from your original dictionary - is that what you wanted?

Comment: i do not have json format but i would like to convert my csv into above formatted way.this you ask for ?